# Why calling .ToList() on an IEnumerable<Entity> with .Where().Select() filters slower than calling it on the Entity itself?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I really hope I have titled this somewhat correctly as I was struggling to put into words what I am asking but...

I am currently trying to get to grips with IEnumerables.

I have a class in my application like so:

```
public class MyDataRepo : IDisposable
{
    private MyEntities context;

    public MyDataRepo()
    { context = new MyEntities(); }

    public IEnumerable<MyItem> GetMyItems()
    { return context.MyItems.AsEnumerable(); }

    public void Dispose()
    { context.Dispose(); }
}
```

I thought then I could use it like so:

```
using (MyDataRepo repo = new MyDataRepo())
{ 
    List<int> MyItemIDs = repo.GetMyItems().Where(x => x.ItemName == "Item Name")
                                           .OrderBy(x => x.ItemMajorIssueNumber)
                                           .ThenBy(x => x.ItemMinorIssueNumber)
                                           .Select(x => x.ItemID).ToList();
}
```

But it is so much slower than just doing this:

```
using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
{
    List<int> MyItemIDs = context.MyItems.Where(x => x.ItemName == "Item Name")
                                         .OrderBy(x => x.ItemMajorIssueNumber)
                                         .ThenBy(x => x.ItemMinorIssueNumber)
                                         .Select(x => x.ItemID).ToList();
}
```

I just wondered why?

From the way I understood it, the `IEnumerable` doesn't execute anything against the database until  `.ToList()` is called.

To me the seem like they should be the same query but the second is almost instant where as the first takes aroud 4-6 seconds.

I appreciate I may of totally mis understood `IEnumerable` and it's usuage though.

I would ideally rather just call the `IEnumerable<>` and apply filters to it then call `.ToList()` to get results I desire than have to write several methods for all the queries against MyItems I will need.

Comment: `AsEnumerable()` fetches all the data (say, 1_000_000 records which takes time) to the workstation where they are filtered, ordered etc. On the contrary `context.MyItems` being `IQueryable` creates *SQL Query* which filters, orders the records on the server side without that huge fetch

Comment: Oh OK so I have misunderstood the AsEnumerable() it seems. I was under the impression it was just building the query, then after I apply the .Where() and .Select() the .ToList() then creates the full query and executes it.

Comment: @Pete that is not incorrect. But IEnumerable filters objects locally, they have to be fetched from database. You should always check queries you send to the database to avoid unpleasant surprises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we have difference with `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` behaviour. When you put

```
  List<int> MyItemIDs = repo
    .GetMyItems()
    .Where(x => x.ItemName == "Item Name")
    ...
```

which is in fact

```
  List<int> MyItemIDs = context
    .MyItems
    .AsEnumerable() <- This is the felony!
    .Where(x => x.ItemName == "Item Name")
    ...
```

you *fetch all the records* (say, all 1_000_000 ones) from RDBMS to the workstation by `.AsEnumerable()` and only then filter them (`Where`), order them (`OrderBy`) etc.

On the contrary

```
 List<int> MyItemIDs = context
   .MyItems
   .Where(x => x.ItemName == "Item Name")
    ...
```

is `IQueryable<T>` up to the very end (`.ToList()`) which means that *SQL query created* and all filtering (`Where`), sorting (`OrderBy`) will be perfomed on *server side* without *unwanted fetch*.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Such a small thing but now makes complete sense. I have removed the AsEnumerable() and chaged the method to return IQeuryable and now it works perfectly as I expected.